# Blazor Server Side Authentication using scaffolded standard routine but without EF Core / Database

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

Just followed a basic tutorial on log in authentication with the scaffolded login standard pages of a blazor server side project under Areas/Identity/... In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntmV9nj4N2Y&t=1177s) video, the process is being explained. Unfortunately, the presenter as well as most of the tutorials are using EF Core to store user data to a db and use this DB for login management. I don't want a database, but I would like to have my own routine to check, of the provided username/password are valid. In particular, I want to make a call to our Active Directory with User/Pass and if the credentials are valid, I log the user in.

I could not find where exactly the EF Core write / read from database happens in the scaffolded views / classes. Can someone explain that to me so that I can plug in at the right place?

Edit: In the meantime, I found the Login.cshtml under Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage, in particular in its model element there's the `OnPostAsync` method which is triggered when I enter user/pass and click the Login button. But I can't get the set up right so that I can hook up right there and perform my own check against AD and just trigger the `_signInManager.SignInAsync()` method. This what I tried but it again starts to try to get data from the entity framework connection, which I don't want it to do:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var user = new IdentityUser("Marc");               
                
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);
               
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);             
                
            }
        }
```

I learned that this line from the Startup.cs is causing this behavior:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

If I change it to

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>();
```

It results in a build error

> "Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory"

And if I remove the line, It builds but as soon as I navigate to the Login page, I get an errror:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'
> while attempting to activate
> 'BlazorApp5.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel'.

What would that line have to look like in order to not execute these EF core DB checks and don't get these errors?

Comment: By default, the Asp.net core Identity using your provides code to use EF core and the relates Manager (such as: UserManager and RoleManager) to manage user and role. If you don't want to use it, just remove this part of code.

Comment: To build a Blazor web app with Azure Active Directory, you could refer to the following links: [How to build a Blazor web app with Azure Active Directory](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/how-to-build-a-blazor-web-app-with-azure-active-directory-authentication-and-microsoft-graph/) and [Adding authentication to a Blazor Server app using Auth0](https://andrewlock.net/adding-authentication-to-a-blazor-server-app-using-auth0/)

Comment: It's not Azure AD, it's an own hosted AD server, hence, this approach won't work for me I think. If I remove the .AddEntityFramworkStores part of that line, I get ...."Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory"